# ios swift app compilation error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am a newbie`iOS` developer and was trying hands on with a sample `iOS` app. The app is giving compilation errors when i tried to build the app using simulator. I tried searching a lot but could not figure out the issue.

Can someone have a look at it and help me ? Most of the errors are for duplicate symbol, but I guess that should not be the problem. Here is the log

```
Ld /Users/dev_mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pulse2Test-etxirlawmrsmegbtjauaclyjuvhp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pulse2Test.app/Pulse2Test normal x86_64
cd /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk -L/Users/dev_mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pulse2Test-etxirlawmrsmegbtjauaclyjuvhp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test -L/Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK -F/Users/dev_mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pulse2Test-etxirlawmrsmegbtjauaclyjuvhp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test -F/Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2Test -filelist /Users/dev_mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pulse2Test-etxirlawmrsmegbtjauaclyjuvhp/Build/Intermediates/Pulse2Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pulse2Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Pulse2Test.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=9.0 -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/dev_mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pulse2Test-etxirlawmrsmegbtjauaclyjuvhp/Build/Intermediates/Pulse2Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pulse2Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Pulse2Test.swiftmodule -framework Pulse2SDK -framework ExternalAccessory -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/dev_mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pulse2Test-etxirlawmrsmegbtjauaclyjuvhp/Build/Intermediates/Pulse2Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pulse2Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Pulse2Test_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/dev_mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pulse2Test-etxirlawmrsmegbtjauaclyjuvhp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pulse2Test.app/Pulse2Test

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK'
duplicate symbol _LED_ROW_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCommonDefs.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNIAPManager.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_COLUMN_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCommonDefs.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNIAPManager.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pulse2Test-etxirlawmrsmegbtjauaclyjuvhp/Build/Intermediates/Pulse2Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pulse2Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LEDPatternTableViewController.o
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNIAPManager.o)
duplicate symbol _PROCOCOL_PACKET_MAX_SIZE in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNDeviceInfo.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNIAPManager.o)
duplicate symbol _PROCOCOL_EMPTY_VALUE in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNDeviceInfo.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNIAPManager.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_ROW_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCommonDefs.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdLedControl.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_COLUMN_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCommonDefs.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdLedControl.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pulse2Test-etxirlawmrsmegbtjauaclyjuvhp/Build/Intermediates/Pulse2Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pulse2Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LEDPatternTableViewController.o
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdLedControl.o)
duplicate symbol _PROCOCOL_PACKET_MAX_SIZE in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNDeviceInfo.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdLedControl.o)
duplicate symbol _PROCOCOL_EMPTY_VALUE in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNDeviceInfo.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdLedControl.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_ROW_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCommonDefs.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdLedPatternInfoResponse.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_COLUMN_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCommonDefs.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdLedPatternInfoResponse.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pulse2Test-etxirlawmrsmegbtjauaclyjuvhp/Build/Intermediates/Pulse2Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pulse2Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LEDPatternTableViewController.o
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdLedPatternInfoResponse.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_ROW_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCommonDefs.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdLedBrightnessResponse.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_COLUMN_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCommonDefs.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdLedBrightnessResponse.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pulse2Test-etxirlawmrsmegbtjauaclyjuvhp/Build/Intermediates/Pulse2Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pulse2Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LEDPatternTableViewController.o
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdLedBrightnessResponse.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_ROW_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCommonDefs.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNDeviceInfo.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_COLUMN_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCommonDefs.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNDeviceInfo.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pulse2Test-etxirlawmrsmegbtjauaclyjuvhp/Build/Intermediates/Pulse2Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pulse2Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LEDPatternTableViewController.o
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNDeviceInfo.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_ROW_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCommonDefs.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdDeviceInfoParser.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_COLUMN_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCommonDefs.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdDeviceInfoParser.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pulse2Test-etxirlawmrsmegbtjauaclyjuvhp/Build/Intermediates/Pulse2Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pulse2Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LEDPatternTableViewController.o
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdDeviceInfoParser.o)
duplicate symbol _PROCOCOL_PACKET_MAX_SIZE in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNDeviceInfo.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdDeviceInfoParser.o)
duplicate symbol _PROCOCOL_EMPTY_VALUE in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNDeviceInfo.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdDeviceInfoParser.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_ROW_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCommonDefs.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNLedControl.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_COLUMN_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCommonDefs.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNLedControl.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pulse2Test-etxirlawmrsmegbtjauaclyjuvhp/Build/Intermediates/Pulse2Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pulse2Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LEDPatternTableViewController.o
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNLedControl.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_ROW_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCommonDefs.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNNotification.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_COLUMN_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCommonDefs.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNNotification.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pulse2Test-etxirlawmrsmegbtjauaclyjuvhp/Build/Intermediates/Pulse2Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pulse2Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LEDPatternTableViewController.o
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNNotification.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_ROW_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCommonDefs.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdSensorControl.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_COLUMN_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCommonDefs.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdSensorControl.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pulse2Test-etxirlawmrsmegbtjauaclyjuvhp/Build/Intermediates/Pulse2Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pulse2Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LEDPatternTableViewController.o
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdSensorControl.o)
duplicate symbol _PROCOCOL_PACKET_MAX_SIZE in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNDeviceInfo.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdSensorControl.o)
duplicate symbol _PROCOCOL_EMPTY_VALUE in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNDeviceInfo.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdSensorControl.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_ROW_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCommonDefs.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdDFU.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_COLUMN_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCommonDefs.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdDFU.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pulse2Test-etxirlawmrsmegbtjauaclyjuvhp/Build/Intermediates/Pulse2Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pulse2Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LEDPatternTableViewController.o
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdDFU.o)
duplicate symbol _PROCOCOL_PACKET_MAX_SIZE in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNDeviceInfo.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdDFU.o)
duplicate symbol _PROCOCOL_EMPTY_VALUE in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNDeviceInfo.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdDFU.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_ROW_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCommonDefs.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNProtocolHandler.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_COLUMN_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCommonDefs.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNProtocolHandler.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pulse2Test-etxirlawmrsmegbtjauaclyjuvhp/Build/Intermediates/Pulse2Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pulse2Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LEDPatternTableViewController.o
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNProtocolHandler.o)
duplicate symbol _PROCOCOL_PACKET_MAX_SIZE in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNDeviceInfo.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNProtocolHandler.o)
duplicate symbol _PROCOCOL_EMPTY_VALUE in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNDeviceInfo.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNProtocolHandler.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pulse2Test-etxirlawmrsmegbtjauaclyjuvhp/Build/Intermediates/Pulse2Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pulse2Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LEDPatternTableViewController.o
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCommonDefs.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_ROW_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCommonDefs.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdVersionResponse.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_COLUMN_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCommonDefs.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdVersionResponse.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pulse2Test-etxirlawmrsmegbtjauaclyjuvhp/Build/Intermediates/Pulse2Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pulse2Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LEDPatternTableViewController.o
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdVersionResponse.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_ROW_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCommonDefs.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdProtocolDef.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_COLUMN_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCommonDefs.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdProtocolDef.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pulse2Test-etxirlawmrsmegbtjauaclyjuvhp/Build/Intermediates/Pulse2Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pulse2Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LEDPatternTableViewController.o
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdProtocolDef.o)
duplicate symbol _PROCOCOL_PACKET_MAX_SIZE in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNDeviceInfo.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdProtocolDef.o)
duplicate symbol _PROCOCOL_EMPTY_VALUE in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNDeviceInfo.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdProtocolDef.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_ROW_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCommonDefs.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdDeviceInfo.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_COLUMN_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCommonDefs.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdDeviceInfo.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pulse2Test-etxirlawmrsmegbtjauaclyjuvhp/Build/Intermediates/Pulse2Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pulse2Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LEDPatternTableViewController.o
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdDeviceInfo.o)
duplicate symbol _PROCOCOL_PACKET_MAX_SIZE in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNDeviceInfo.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdDeviceInfo.o)
duplicate symbol _PROCOCOL_EMPTY_VALUE in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNDeviceInfo.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdDeviceInfo.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_ROW_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCommonDefs.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdDeviceInfoResponse.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_COLUMN_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCommonDefs.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdDeviceInfoResponse.o)
duplicate symbol _LED_COUNT in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pulse2Test-etxirlawmrsmegbtjauaclyjuvhp/Build/Intermediates/Pulse2Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pulse2Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LEDPatternTableViewController.o
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdDeviceInfoResponse.o)
duplicate symbol _PROCOCOL_PACKET_MAX_SIZE in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNDeviceInfo.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdDeviceInfoResponse.o)
duplicate symbol _PROCOCOL_EMPTY_VALUE in:
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNDeviceInfo.o)
    /Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK.framework/Pulse2SDK(HMNCmdDeviceInfoResponse.o)
ld: 64 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project?

Comment: @Callam clean did not worked. I tried it earlier as well.

Comment: @Idan I don't have any .m file, so that solution did not worked. :(

Comment: Okay well that was me just asking if you've tried turning off and on again. The error is saying it can't find a particular directory that you've included in the project. It's a directory in your Downloads that you have most likely deleted. If you can find the directory in your Trash Bin, you can restore it and attempt to run the project then.

Comment: If you're unable to find the folder in your Trash Bin, you can redownload the SDK here http://www.developer.harman.com/site/global/developer_tools/pulse2_sdk/index.gsp

Comment: There are so many similar questions. It happens frequently, I think since clean the project didn't work, try and revert your steps until the last run and until the error is gone.

Comment: @Callam actually i am directly running their sample over there. Thats the one failing. let me post the directory structure. I guess i found the problem. Not sure how to fix it. The directory inside code repo is differently named. Check the picture added to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is occurring because a directory doesn't exist. You can try removing the reference to the directory in your project to solve the issue. You do this by going to you projects ***Build Settings*** and searching for ***Library Search Paths***. You need to find any reference to the directory `/Users/dev_mac/Downloads/Pulse2Test/Pulse2SDK` and remove it.

Comment: Directory error gone. still no luck. :(

ld: 64 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Build Settings > Other Linker Flags**, you'll find a reference of the directory missing, remove that along with it’s “-framework” in the list.